# Building mutli dimensional array filter with es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, ecmascript-6

As shown in the Screenshot im trying to build a Filter logic which cannot be handeled in backend/sql for other reasons.

[image]

Im getting Product Data and the filters have to be additive to each other.
To achieve filtering by 1 property id ( filter by brand id or category id  for example) i built such function:

```
multiFilter (arr, filters)  {

    const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);

    return arr.filter(eachObj => {
        return filterKeys.every(eachKey => {

            if (!filters[eachKey].length) {
                return true;
            }
            return filters[eachKey].includes(eachObj[eachKey].id);
        });
    });
}
```

- Argument arr is the Product array
- Argument Filters is the information what filters are active.
  like for example:

  ```
       {
          "brands" : [4,6,8],
          "categorys" : [7,2,4,5],
          "additives" : [1,2,3,4,6,8,9,54,32,12]   
       }
  ```

this works as long as filtered by brand id or category id on one level of a product.

what im trying to to do now is, to additionally filter products by additives for example, which are one level deeper as you can see in my screenshot.
any ideas how to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

```
multiFilter (arr, filters)  {

    const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);

    return arr.filter(eachObj => {
        return filterKeys.every(eachKey => {

            if (!filters[eachKey].length) {
                return true;
            }

            if(eachObj[eachKey].id) {
                return filters[eachKey].includes(eachObj[eachKey].id );
            } else {
                return filters[eachKey].some(f => eachObj[eachKey].some(v => v.id === f));
            }
        });
    });

}
```

---->

```
       return filters[eachKey].some(f => eachObj[eachKey].some(v => v.id === f));
```